# "Submit Private Plugin" on build.phonegap.com from a paid account is not working?

Tags: plugins, phonegap-build, private

I have a paid account and I would like to submit a private plugin, but it look like this functionality is not working.
When I am putting the URL - it says that is valid URL from my gitHub private repo. I also completed the branch with "master".
After I press the button for submit it take about one minute to redirect me to build.phonegap.com/plugins, where I get a white page.
Wen I refresh the page again and check the "Your Plugins" tag - it says :"You have no submitted plugins."

The documentation for submitting a private plugin on a paid account is very poor.
Can someone help me?

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Lydia

Comment: When I'm adding git plugins, I just use <plugin spec="https://github.com/example/cordova-plugin.git" source="git" /> in the config.xml. However I don't think it will work with a private repository. The same thing goes when adding from the interface. If it's not asking for authentication in github, then it can't access the plugin.

Comment: I'm revoking my previous comment. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, your github account should be linked to your phonegap build account, which is done from your account settings. This will allow the build service to access your private repos.

Then all you have to do is add a plugin tag in your config.xml. Something like:

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/example/cordova-plugin.git" source="git" />
```

ref: http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/02/16/git-plugins/

Then just build like usual. The phonegap build service will download the plugin and include it in the build.